# Python data structure to represent an unlimited tree with attributes and looping until last depth

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of Categories on multiple levels/depths:

```
1. A
   - A1
     - A11
     - A12
       - A121 
       - A122
     -A2
2. B
3. C
   - C1
   - C2
```

I need

1. to represent this categories in a python data structure. I have about lists in lists but I think it doesn't help me, because I need to know the depth relation and name of the Category (A, A1, A2)

l= [ A -> [A1] -> [A12] -> [A121, A122]]

2. Loop thru the all list of categories go to the last depth and choose randomly one of the categories

For example:

- first element A, go to the last depth and randomly om choose between A121 and A122
- third element C, choose randomly between C1, C2

First, for testing, I will create the structure manually, but I want to import later from a CSV

Comment: Sounds like a plan, and your question is?

Comment: In what form is the data stored currently, please share an example.

Comment: Please refer this link https://pypi.org/project/anytree/

Comment: @zipa  the data is no stored, first I want to do a manual data structure, then import from a file like csv or web

Comment: @zwer , well my question is in 'I need' part, because I don't know how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could use a third Party Python Package, called anytree form https://pypi.org/project/anytree/

```
pip install anytree
```

## code.py

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

A = Node("A")
A1 =  Node ("A1", parent=A)
A11 = Node("A11", parent = A1)
A12 = Node("A12", parent = A1)
A121 = Node("A121", parent = A12)
A122 = Node("A122", parent = A12)
A2 = Node("A2", parent=A1)
B = Node("B")
C = Node("C")
C1 = Node("C1", parent=C)
C2 = Node("C2", parent=C)

print (A)
print(A122)

for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(A):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

Output

```
============= RESTART: C:/Python36/MyTestScripts/anytree_test.py =============
Node('/A')
Node('/A/A1/A12/A122')
A
└── A1
    ├── A11
    ├── A12
    │   ├── A121
    │   └── A122
    └── A2
>>>
```

Comment: what is the structure used behind, to represent data ?, because first I want to use a manual structure, to do test parts of code, before using the csv

Comment: If you could refer to the Node.py after installing anytree, Node is basically an Class Object with two data members, (self.name, self.parent), Name of that node and its parent. which keeps on growing as the number of nodes increase